# Resolver condicional

Tags: php, foreach

Eu tenho um `if` que não está sendo satisfeito nunca.

Eu acho que eu to usando algum *loop* de forma errada. Eu já conferi o valor de todas as variáveis, e estão todas corretas.

Então vou passar aqui valores das variáveis e vocês, se puderem, analisem porque o `if` não é satisfeito.

```
<?php
session_start();
//Aqui eu pego o numero de cartelas que o usuário informou em outra pag.
$ncarts = $_SESSION['ncarts'];
//pego o numero de pedras de cada cartela que o usuario informou em outra pag. 
$npedras = $_SESSION['npedras'];
// Pego a quantidade de pedras que vão ser sorteadas, inserido em outra pag.
$quantidade_sorteada = $_SESSION['quantidade_sorteada'];
/*inicio a array, posteriormente usada para guardar os números de cada cartela, sendo que cada indice é uma cartela, e seus valores são as pedras dessa cartela*/
$numeros_cartela = array();
/*inicio a array que guardará os valores que foram sorteados pelo usuário, cada índice tem apenas um valor, exemplo, sorteado 1 = 2, sorteado 3 = 12, etc...*/
$sorted = array();
/* aqui eu conto o numero de acertos que cada cartela faz, sendo que cada índice começa valendo zero - óbvio.*/
$contador_pontos_cartela = array();

/* Cada cartela quando é registrada em outra página tem um arquivo criado, para guardar seus valores. Esse arquivo tem o formato "cartela{$p).txt", onde $p é o numero da cartela. Então eu salvo cada linha do arquivo em um índice do array $numeros_cartela */
for ($p=1; $p<=$ncarts; $p++) {
$numeros_cartela[$p] = file ("cartela{$p}.txt"); 
}

/*Eu em outra página peguei os números sorteados, cada um em um campo com name variável. E orientei o form com GET, para esse arquivo aqui. Por isso cada número que o usuário digitou como sendo os sorteados, serão salvos em um array $sorted*/
for ($k=1; $k<=$quantidade_sorteada; $k++) {
$sorted[$k] = $_GET["numero$k"]; 
}

//aqui eu percorro as cartelas
for ($p=1; $p<=$ncarts; $p++) {
//inicio o contador da cartela como zero
$contador_pontos_cartela[$p] = 0;
for ($g=1; $g<=$quantidade_sorteada; $g++) {
/*cada cartela possui um índice, no array $numeros_cartela, então eu vou percorrer cada cartela, passando cada elemento da cartela para a variável $w.*/
foreach ($numeros_cartela[$p] as $w) {
// exibo os valores envolvidos na condicional, só para ver se estão certos
echo "Valor de w: {$w}<br>";
echo "Valor de sorted: {$sorted[$g]}<br>";
//confere se o numero sorteado é igual ao némero da cartela de índice $p
if ($w == $sorted[$g]){
//se for igual, soma 1 ao contador da cartela analisada
$contador_pontos_cartela[$p] += 1;
// esse echo foi só para ver se o problema era no if realmente...
echo "somou";
     }
    }
  }
}
// aqui eu imprimo na tela o número de acertos de cada cartela
for ($t=1; $t<=$ncarts; $t++) {
echo "Acertos cartela {$t}: {$contador_pontos_cartela[$t]}<br>";
}
?>
```

Suponha então que:

```
$ncarts = 3;
$quantidade_sorteada = 3;
$sorted[1] = 1;
$sorted[2] = 3;
$sorted[3] = 5;
$numeros_cartela[1] = array(1, 3);
$numeros_cartela[2] = array(5, 7);
$numeros_cartela[3] = array(9, 11);
```

Com isso, pelo que eu tinha calculado, o último `echo` - lá o final - retornaria:

```
Acertos cartela 1: 2
Acertos cartela 2: 1
Acertos cartela 3: 0
```

Mas o retorno é:

```
Acertos cartela 1: 0
Acertos cartela 2: 0
Acertos cartela 3: 0
```

E o retorno daquele `echo` antes do `if` é:

```
Valor de w: 1 
Valor de sorted: 1
Valor de w: 3 
Valor de sorted: 1
Valor de w: 1 
Valor de sorted: 3
Valor de w: 3 
Valor de sorted: 3
Valor de w: 1 
Valor de sorted: 5
Valor de w: 3 
Valor de sorted: 5
Valor de w: 5 
Valor de sorted: 1
Valor de w: 7 
Valor de sorted: 1
Valor de w: 5 
Valor de sorted: 3
Valor de w: 7 
Valor de sorted: 3
Valor de w: 5 
Valor de sorted: 5
Valor de w: 7 
Valor de sorted: 5
Valor de w: 9 
Valor de sorted: 1
Valor de w: 11 
Valor de sorted: 1
Valor de w: 9 
Valor de sorted: 3
Valor de w: 11 
Valor de sorted: 3
Valor de w: 9 
Valor de sorted: 5
Valor de w: 11 
Valor de sorted: 5
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê de ter esse resultado?

Comment: Pode colocar comentários no seu código para perceber melhor a sua lógica?

Comment: Vou fazer isso.

Comment: Pronto. Expliquei direitinho, olha lá. Espero que entenda.

Comment: Zebra, por acaso é a mesma pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14688/estrutura-com-for-if-foreach-problema

Comment: @ZebraDoMal nunca imprime o somou?

Comment: @ZebraDoMal faz um print de `$w` e de `$sorted[$g]` antes do if a ver que valores tomam.

Comment: @brasofilo Não é a mesma.

Comment: @JorgeB. Nunca imprime o somou. Justamente para isso que eu coloquei ele ali, só para ver se iria imprimi-lo, me dando certeza nesse caso que a condicional não foi satisfeita.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu já fiz isso Jorge! E os valores estão corretos, por via das dúvidas, adicionei na pergunta, olha lá.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descobri qual o problema!

O que eu fiz; dei um `var_dump` em cima do `if`, e notei que a variável `$w` contém espaços vazios antes dela. Usei a função `trim()` do PHP, removi os espaços, e tudo funcionou perfeitamente.